# Secure Google Cloud Functions Calls from Server-Side, Authentication strategy?

Tags: python, amazon-ec2, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, service-accounts

I have developed a `Google Cloud Function (GCF)` in python, which i want to access from a web service deployed on AWS (written in python). While in the development phase of the `GCF`, It had `Cloud Function Invoker` permission set to `allUsers`. I assume that is why it didn't ask for an `Authorization Token` when called.

I want to revoke this public access and make it so that i can only call this function from the web service code and it is not accessible public-ally.

**Possible Approach** :In my research i have found out that this can be done using the following steps:

1. Removing all the unnecessary members who have permissions to the GCF.
2. Creating a new service account which has restricted access to only use GCF.
3. Download the service account key (json) and use it in the AWS web application
4. Set environment variable `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` equal to the path of that service account key (json) file.

**Questions**

1. How to generate the Access token using the service account, which may then be appended as `Authorization Bearer` within the HTTP call made to the `GCF`? Without this token the `GCF` should throw error.
2. The [docs](https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/production#best_practices_for_managing_credentials) say not to put the service account key in the source code. Then what is the best way to go about it. They suggest to use KMS which seems like an overkill.

> Do not embed secrets related to authentication in source code, such as API keys, OAuth tokens, and service account credentials. You can use an environment variable pointing to credentials outside of the application's source code, such as Cloud Key Management Service.

3. What are the bare minimum permissions i will require for the service account?

Please feel free to correct me if you think my understanding is wrong and there is a better and preferable way to do it.

UPDATE: The web service on AWS will call the `GCF` in a server-to-server fashion. There is no need to propagate the client-end (end-user) credentials.

Comment: The authorization for Cloud Functions does not use Access Tokens, instead, OIDC identity Tokens are used. The identity of the user is used and not permissions. This means no permissions (roles) are required for the service account itself. The permissions for the identity are granted thru the Invoker role applied to the Cloud Function and not to the service account (or the user account).

Comment: #2. This means that you will need a service account JSON key file for your service in AWS. You will use this service account to generate an Identity Token and include this token in the HTTP Header `authorization: bearer <token>`.

Comment: #3) For AWS to ensure the security of the service account, use AWS Secrets Manager to store and retrieve the JSON contents of the service account.

Comment: Thank alot @JohnHanley, i will try this and will comment if there is some confusion. 
just to be clear, in 2# you are referring to something like this? 
https://github.com/salrashid123/salrashid123.github.io/blob/master/google_id_token/python/googleidtokens.py
Please see the `GetIDTokenFromServiceAccount` function

Comment: That example code will generate an Identity Token. Google also provides an endpoint to fetch the Identity Token which is probably a better choice on AWS. Here is a curl example: `curl -H "Authorization: Bearer $ACCESS_TOKEN" https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/userinfo` With your favorite requests library you can make an HTTP GET request to that endpoint with the access token for authorization. The returned JSON contains the Identity Token.

Answer (score 1):

1. In your description, you don't mention who/what will call your GCF. A user? A Compute? Another GCF? However, this [page](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/securing/authenticating) can help you to find code example
2. Yes, secret in plain text and pushed on GIT is not yet a secret! Here again, I don't know what performing the call. If it's a compute, functions, cloud run, or any service of GCP, don't use JSON file key, but the component identity. I would say, create a service account and set it to this component. Tell me more on where are you deploying if you want more help!
3. Related to 2: if you have a service account, what the minimal role: cloudfunctions.Invoker. It's the minimal role to invoke function

```
gcloud beta functions add-iam-policy-binding RECEIVING_FUNCTION \
  --member='serviceAccount:CALLING_FUNCTION_IDENTITY' \
  --role='roles/cloudfunctions.invoker'
```

Comment: Thanks for answering.
1- Apologies, i didn't mention that part. its actually a server-to-server thing. i have updated the question also. 
2- The web-service which will call the function is a flask service, but is deployed on aws, Hence i cant use the ADS authentication which is used within the google cloud's ecosystem.
3- The code you shared i think refers to a gcf calling another gcf. which means both exist in google cloud platform. but in my case the webservice is in AWS

Comment: No problem, but if you call from GCP you have the Answer. Prefer the comments of @JohnHanley, he is a killer on GCP and AWS !